# Ruby + Appium - Locator Strategy 'name' is not supported for this session

Tags: ruby, session, appium

```
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:69:in `assert_ok': Locator Strategy 'name' is not supported for this session (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidSelectorError)
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:32:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:83:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:83:in `create_response'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:107:in `request'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:61:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:678:in `raw_execute'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:656:in `execute'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:625:in `find_element_by'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/appium_lib-9.4.3/lib/appium_lib/device/device.rb:440:in `find_element'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/appium_lib-9.4.3/lib/appium_lib/driver.rb:739:in `find_element'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/appium_lib-9.4.3/lib/appium_lib/driver.rb:242:in `rescue in block (4 levels) in promote_appium_methods'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/appium_lib-9.4.3/lib/appium_lib/driver.rb:233:in `block (4 levels) in promote_appium_methods'
        from tindermation.rb:46:in `like_button'
        from tindermation.rb:75:in `<main>'
Looking for girls to match...
```

Apparently `name` is deprecated in Appium? What is the alternative? Is there some setting in Android Developer Options that will return the xpath, id, class name, accessibility id, etc. for particular UI elements?

Alternatively, I'm using Developer Options to click a UI element at a certain coordinate. For example:

```
def login_button
  sleep 1
  driver.execute_script 'mobile: tap', :x => 539, :y => 1464, :fingers => 1, :tapCount => 1, :duration => 0.5
  sleep 1
  driver.execute_script 'mobile: tap', :x => 871, :y => 1130, :fingers => 1, :tapCount => 1, :duration => 0.5
  sleep 1
end
```

But I get this exception:

```
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:69:in `assert_ok': Method has not yet been implemented (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)
```

Why can't I tap the login button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you need to use either xpath or id.
Alternatively if you have name you can use xpath as
`//*[@name='yourName']` .

`driver.find_element(xpath: "//*[@name='yourName']").click`

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Yup, this works. Hard part is getting your APK to work so you can find the name. Alternatively ``Appium::TouchAction.new.tap( x: 880, y:1129, count: 3).release.perform`` performs a tap at the desired X,Y location.

Comment: Glad it worked, tap on fixed location is always risky because every device will have different resolution and x,y coordinates will change according. 
Better try to get dynamic coordinates, if possible, otherwise the dirty way is the only way. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use ["Appium Inspector"](https://github.com/appium/appium-dot-app), the inbuilt tool with Appium GUI app or the Android SDK tool ["uiautomatorviewer"](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_ui_testing.htm) to find the different attributes of UI components of the app.

Comment: What about a command like ``driver.execute_script 'mobile: tap', :x => 539, :y => 1464, :fingers => 1, :tapCount => 1, :duration => 0.5``
? I'm also getting exceptions, as noted above in my updated post. The project is located here: https://github.com/santafebound/tindermation

Comment: Are you trying to automate Web App or Native App?

Comment: Native. There is no Tinder web app